# Некорректное отображение сообщения об ошибке (MaskEdit в IBDataSet)

Tags: delphi, исключения, firebird, interbase

У меня есть `Dataset`, в котором есть поле `Field1`, которое имеет свойство `EditMask = '00000000;1;_'` (важно, чтобы пользователь именно видел количество необходимых символов).
При вводе не всего количества чисел, формируется исключение класса **EDBEditError**.
Я пытаюсь его поймать:

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  Application.OnException := AppException; 
end; 

procedure TForm2.AppException(Sender: TObject; E: Exception); 
begin 
  if E is EDBEditError then 
    Вывод сообщения; 
end;
```

Оно ловится, выводится сообщение – все нормально.
Но т.к. это форма 2, то после выдачи сообщения, она **прячется**.
Вопросы:

1. Как сделать так, чтобы она не пряталась? (`Form2.Show` - не помогает).
2. Насколько корректна такая обработка исключения?

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: "т.к. это форма 2, то после выдачи сообщения, она прячется." - ??

Comment: на счет формы разобрался. Ответьте пожалуйста на второй вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

*Отвечаю на второй вопрос.*

Такая обработка исключения некорректна. Представьте, что каждая форма будет так делать. Что из этого получится?

Возможно, Вам подойдет `TDataSet.OnEditError`:

http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DB_TDataSet_OnEditError.html